# Want to show a menu bar over image modal in "react-native-image-layout" to provide option for image like delete, etc

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Background: So I am Implementing react-native-image-layout to create a gallery view where you can click on the image and then the image appears on modal and then you have headers and footers where you can add buttons which can do some functionality like close the modal n all.

Example: Now I want something like this: [like there is a menu popped over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P0EV.jpg)

My Implementation: And this is where I actually want it. [The ImageViewer I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXuiD.jpg) <--- I want the menu when I click that dot-horizontal button.